# Protractor Manually Bootstrap Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have an Angularjs 1.6.7 app that I am trying to use Protractor 5.1.2 to run e2e tests on.  It works fine if I run the tests in a windowed environment, but as soon as I set the `--headless` flag for Chrome, Protractor can no longer find Angular.  The app is manually bootstrapped, which I have read has caused a huge headache for everyone.  There are posts that say it is fixed, there are some that say there are work-arounds, etc., but nothing seems to fix the issue.

If I add the ng-app to the body and remove the manual bootstrap call, the e2e tests pass.  I've tried doing something like this in a beforeEach:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    return browser.get(webpage)
        .then(() => {
            //Injects a global variable to indicate that E2E tests are running
            return browser.executeScript(function(){ window['RUNNINGE2E'] = true; });
        })
        .then(() => {
            return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element(by.css('body.ng-scope'))), 60000, "ng-scope never added to body tag");
        })
        .then(() => {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        });
```

That should wait for the ng-scope class to be added to the body tag before continuing, but it reaches the timeout after 60 seconds.  Any ideas why the tests work in windowed mode, but not headless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles upon this post, manually bootstrapped apps should work given the versions I mentioned above. There is an issue with invalid certs in headless mode [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4591), which should be resolved with chrome driver 2.35 and chrome 65, but that wasn't applicable here

In my case, the app was failing during the bootstrap process because it couldn't hit an endpoint since the origin is 'none' in headless mode.  A simple catch and returning a default fixed the `$http.get` issue, so the script continued and bootstrapped the app.  You may need to increase the getPageTimeout protractor option if it still fails.

Also a heads up, you shouldn't need to ignoreSynchronization either, unless you really do hit a page that isn't using Angular.